# keep some sort of c++ object alive over multiple jni calls

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

My java code will call the exist c++ code to parse the file. it will generate an object which keep many data. 
I will call the jni's second method to access such data,
When I call the second method, I have to parse the file again. it is obviously the right behavior.

Is there a way to handle this ?
BTW: I am newly to c++.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking if there is a way to parse the file once in C++?  The answer is certainly yes.  Perhaps you could explain what you have attempted to solve this problem and what issues you en-counted.

Comment: first, I call jni method parseFile();

Comment: first, I call jni method parseFile()(c++ code) and return some data to java. after that, accoridng user's action, such as touch a button, I will call another jni method selectNote(), in the second jni method's c++ code, it will use the data that parseFile() produce, so I have to call parseFile() again in selectNote() (c++ code).

Comment: If you want to cache the result from the first run of parseFile(), you could first check if the file name is the same and it has not been modified, then you could re-use the data structure from the previous call (otherwise clean up the structure)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correct. But I guess what you want to do is to keep some sort of c++ object alive over multiple jni calls.

You can do multiple things. First parse your file and store your c++ object in a global variable. This is the simplest solution but not a nice one.

You can also move the life cycle of your c++ object into java.

```
jlong java_some_class_jni_method(...)
{
    .... parse your text file ....
    MyParseclass* cls = new MyParseclass(...);
    ....
    return (jlong) cls;
}
```

But keep in mind that you need to delete this native c++ class again. So you need a jni method to this and be sure to call it.

```
void java_some_calls_jni_method(..., jlong clsPtr)
{
    MyParseclass* cls = (MyParseclass*)clsPtr;
    ... do maybe do something with cls and access the data...
    delete cls; // do not use the jlong again in any call
}
```

BTW: It would be much more helpful if you would post some code. But I hope this pseudo code here helps a little.

Comment: Great. This is what I want. I will try.

Comment: @DavidGuo after delete cls i am still able to access object from java long , and native memory is not reduced after deleting

Comment: I think you have to remove any reference to cls in your java code so there is no stack with a variable having reference to cls in which case it will be deleted. (when the creating frame is exited from the stack the JNI local references are deleted). Finally, the native objects will be garbage collected as they have no references.

Answer (score 7):

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808610/android-ndk-keeping-live-c-objects)

Here's my solution to keeping objects alive on C++ in order to reference them from multiple JNI calls:

**Java**

On the Java side, I am creating a class with a `long` pointer to keep a reference to the C++ object. Wrapping the C++ methods in a Java class, allows us to use the C++ methods in multiple activities. Notice that I am creating the C++ object on the constructor, and I am deleting the object on cleanup. This is very important in order to prevent memory leaks:

```
public class JavaClass {
    // Pointer (using long to account for 64-bit OS)
    private long objPtr = 0;

    // Create C++ object
    public JavaClass() {
        createCppObject();
    }

    // Delete C++ object on cleanup
    public void cleanup() {
        deleteCppObject();
        this.objPtr = 0;
    }

    // Native methods
    public native void createCppObject();
    public native void workOnCppObject();
    public native void deleteCppObject();

    // Load C++ shared library
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("CppLib");
    }

}
```

**C++**

On the C++ side, I am defining functions to create, modify and delete the object. It's important to mention that we have to use `new` and `delete` to store the object in the HEAP memory to keep it alive throughout the lifecycle of the Java class instances. I am also storing the pointer to `CppObject` straight in the `JavaClass`, using `getFieldId`, `SetLongField`, and `GetLongField`:

```
// Get pointer field straight from `JavaClass`
jfieldID getPtrFieldId(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    static jfieldID ptrFieldId = 0;

    if (!ptrFieldId)
    {
        jclass c = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
        ptrFieldId = env->GetFieldID(c, "objPtr", "J");
        env->DeleteLocalRef(c);
    }

    return ptrFieldId;
}

// Methods to create, modify, and delete Cpp object
extern "C" {

    void Java_com_test_jnitest_JavaClass_createCppObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        env->SetLongField(obj, getPtrFieldId(env, obj), (jlong) new CppObject);
    }

    void Java_com_test_jnitest_JavaClass_workOnCppObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        CppObject* cppObj = (CppObject*) env->GetLongField(obj, getPtrFieldId(env, obj));

        // Write your code to work on CppObject here
    }

    void Java_com_test_jnitest_JavaClass_deleteCppObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        CppObject* cppObj = (CppObject*) env->GetLongField(obj, getPtrFieldId(env, obj));

        delete cppObj;
    } 

}
```

**NOTES:**

- Unlike Java, C++ does not have garbage collection, and the object will live on the HEAP memory, until you use `delete`.
- I am using `GetFieldID`, `SetLongField`, and `GetLongField` to store the object reference from C++, but you could also store the `jlong` object pointer from Java as discussed on other answers.
- On my final code, I implemented the `JavaObject` class as a `Parcelable` in order to pass my class to multiple activities using `Intent` with extras.

Comment: C++ does have garbage collection. It also has RAII, which Java does not have.