# Android NDK, keeping live C++ objects

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I've got a following problem. I want to write an Android application, which uses my legacy C++ classes. I have to keep a C++ object alive during the whole application lifetime.

I wrote a similar application in C# and solved the problem by passing a pointer to a C++ class to C# and storing it there using IntPtr. Then, when I wanted to call a method on that object, I simply passed that pointer again to C++, converted to a class pointer and called a method on it.

How can I achieve similar result in Java and Android NDK? Does Java support storing pointers?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can do the exact same than what you did in C#.

To create your new C++ Object:

```
jlong
Java_package_name_new(JNIEnv *, jobject) {
  return (long)(new CPP_Object()); 
}
```

You can store the return value of this method in a Java `ptr` variable, and pass it to all NDK methods that need it:

```
void
Java_package_name_doSomething(JNIEnv *, jobject, jlong ptr) {
  CPP_Object *obj = (CPP_Object *)ptr;
  // do whatever you want with the object
}
```

And finally delete it with something like:

```
void
Java_package_name_delete(JNIEnv *, jobject, jlong ptr) {
  delete (CPP_Object *)(ptr);
}
```

Instead of passing `ptr` to all methods that need it, you can also get it and set it directly from the NDK part using the `SetLongField` and `GetLongField` methods: this allows the Java `ptr` variable to be managed only from the NDK part of the code, which I find safer and easier to manage.

Comment: Please use `long`/`jlong` rather than `int`/`jint` for pointers; otherwise the code will break if pointers become 64-bit.

Comment: Perfectly right, 64-bit is probably going to happen quite soon on Android (Apple just did it). Fixing my answer!

Comment: greate answer @mbrenon, thanks! can you please show how to use SetLongField and GetLongField?

Comment: The disadvantage I've seen of using `GetLongField` is that you have to store the field ID as a static variable, which can be a problem if you need to have multiple instances of the C object. Alternatively, you can call `GetFieldID` on each call into JNI, but then you incur a lookup cost. Or you can pass the field ID back to Java, which is kind of messy, because now you have to keep members in your Java class for both the field and field ID. I'm no Java expert, though, and welcome anyone to tell me I'm wrong, so I can learn something.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit late to the conversation, but since I couldn't find an SO post that answers this question thoroughly, I'll post my solution.

**Java**

On the Java side, I am creating a class with a `long` pointer to keep a reference to the C++ object. Wrapping the C++ methods in a Java class, allows us to use the C++ methods in multiple activities. Notice that I am creating the C++ object on the constructor, and I am deleting the object on cleanup. This is very important in order to prevent memory leaks:

```
public class JavaClass {
    // Pointer (using long to account for 64-bit OS)
    private long objPtr = 0;

    // Create C++ object
    public JavaClass() {
        createCppObject();
    }

    // Delete C++ object on cleanup
    public void cleanup() {
        deleteCppObject();
        this.objPtr = 0;
    }

    // Native methods
    public native void createCppObject();
    public native void workOnCppObject();
    public native void deleteCppObject();

    // Load C++ shared library
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("CppLib");
    }

}
```

**C++**

On the C++ side, I am defining functions to create, modify and delete the object. It's important to mention that we have to use `new` and `delete` to store the object in the HEAP memory to keep it alive throughout the lifecycle of the Java class instances. I am also storing the pointer to `CppObject` straight in the `JavaClass`, using `getFieldId`, `SetLongField`, and `GetLongField`:

```
// Get pointer field straight from `JavaClass`
jfieldID getPtrFieldId(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    static jfieldID ptrFieldId = 0;

    if (!ptrFieldId)
    {
        jclass c = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
        ptrFieldId = env->GetFieldID(c, "objPtr", "J");
        env->DeleteLocalRef(c);
    }

    return ptrFieldId;
}

// Methods to create, modify, and delete Cpp object
extern "C" {

    void Java_com_test_jnitest_JavaClass_createCppObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        env->SetLongField(obj, getPtrFieldId(env, obj), (jlong) new CppObject);
    }

    void Java_com_test_jnitest_JavaClass_workOnCppObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        CppObject* cppObj = (CppObject*) env->GetLongField(obj, getPtrFieldId(env, obj));

        // Write your code to work on CppObject here
    }

    void Java_com_test_jnitest_JavaClass_deleteCppObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        CppObject* cppObj = (CppObject*) env->GetLongField(obj, getPtrFieldId(env, obj));

        delete cppObj;
    } 

}
```

**NOTES:**

- Unlike Java, C++ does not have garbage collection, and the object will live on the HEAP memory, until you use `delete`.
- I am using `GetFieldID`, `SetLongField`, and `GetLongField` to store the object reference from C++, but you could also store the `jlong` object pointer from Java as discussed on other answers.
- On my final code, I implemented the `JavaObject` class as a `Parcelable` in order to pass my class to multiple activities using `Intent` with extras.

Answer (score 1):

You could also wrap your C++ code using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org), where you instantiate your native Object by constructing it in Java, and as long as you hold a reference to it, it isn't destroyed (losing the reference makes it eligible for garbage collection which will invoke the destructor on the C++ Object instance when the Java reference is finalized).

However, if the interaction between native code and Java code is minimal, using SWIG might be too OTT.