# Android NDK: keeping alive C++ objects

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, garbage-collection

I've read this post and the answer on how to keep C++ object alive.

[Android NDK, keeping live C++ objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808610/android-ndk-keeping-live-c-objects)

But I have something still don't understand.
I know that jlong can store a memory address, but isn't the jlong store only the initial address of that C++ object?
If so, the Dalvik GC will not know where the memory of the object ends, that mean the C++ instance could be destroyed by GC when we still need it. How could I prevent this happen?

Or does the C++ instance stay in something like the native heap without the management of GC, so the object would be safely stay in memory which only needs explicit freeing memory function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is correct. C++ objects are created in the native heap, which is not controlled by JVM. Therefore, the garbage collector never has access to these objects. Even if you use some mechanism to keep C++ pointers in your Java, they are just unknown **jlong**s for Java, and Dalvik still does not know how these objects can be destroyed or otherwise manipulated.

Comment: I've seen someone saying that keeping C++ instance is unsafe, but if it was not unsafe because of GC and JVM, what could be the unsafe factor, or is it safe at all? thx

Comment: Keeping C++ object pointers in your Java app is unsafe because the native object could be deleted (by native code itself), and the same address could be reused by an entirely different object (maybe of a different type), while Java will not know about that. The above is not a death sentence: you simply should be aware of this unsafety, and build a framework by which Java and native code would track and handle such situations. There are other tricky situations, as well.

Comment: What will happen if Java doesn't notice changes in the native heap? Or does the changes not just affect the native heap? Or the problem would be not enough memory because GC don't know and so memory are not cleaned up?

Comment: Imagine the following scenario: your native code has two classes, `CreditCardInfo` and `DeliveryAddress`. You create an instance of address, fill it with not-particularly-sensitive data, and store the "object" (i.e., `DeliveryAddress*`) in your Java class. After some while, your Java calls a native method to send the stored delivery address to the pizza boy. In the meanwhile, the native code deleted the object, and created a `CreditCardInfo` object that happened to be located at same address. As a result, you confidential info is sent to the wild.

Comment: Ic what you are talking about, the object might be deleted and replace by something else object, but you mean delete manually (by either simple or complicated logic behind) or it has any chance to be deleted automatically?

Comment: Well, in C++ there is automatic object destruction, based on scope. Consider a function that has a local object of `DeliveryAddress` type. You can pass the address to a Java callback, and the object will be destroyed when your function returns (see http://pastebin.com/AqzS0arB).

Comment: But what is the different of creating an native object inside native function and return a jlong instead of a 0 just like what other people said?

Comment: I don't understand your question. [This code](http://pastebin.com/AqzS0arB) is for illustration purposes only. It gives an extremely simple example of automatic delete which you asked about. Being so much simplified, it's obvious that this is an anti-pattern. It is much more natural to _return_ the pointer as **jint**. But still not fool-proof.

Comment: Do u mean the DeliveryAddress instance would be deleted automatically because of not declaring it by DeliveryAddress*? Ive seen people saying that declaring an instance with pointer of object would need explicit delete.

Comment: They are right. But keep in mind that scenarios may be much less straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, your answers are helpful