# Store obejcts/strings in CPP jni

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

What is the best way to keep around things in cpp when writing Android code. I am running some OpenCV code on eacht frame. I have multiple objects I want to keep around, that I don't always want to recreate. Examples are strings like a path, a OpenCV Face detector class. Currently I only have one class I keep around and I pass it around from Java to CPP as a pointer. But now that I want to add more that seems like not a good idea.

Any hints on how to solve this efficiently?

Currently I am doing something similar to this: [Android NDK, keeping live C++ objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808610/android-ndk-keeping-live-c-objects)

I was already not a fan of the solution before but now I want to have multiple objects which makes the code even more messy

Comment: C++ objects or Java objects? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I have C++ objects. I added a link describing what I am currently doing

Comment: And what in that question doesn't answer your problem?

Comment: So now if I have 5 different detectors I will have a JNI call for each of them to create and delete them. And also pass them around. Or I put everything into one, but what happens then if I want to disable one of them. Seems like a not very flexible solution

Answer (score 1):

You can create a C++ class to hold all objects you need as members.

**Header file:**

```
class MyCppClass
{
public:
    MyCppClass();
    ~MyCppClass();
    //Any other methods you need

    std::string mPath;
    //Any other member variables
}
```

**Source File:**

```
static MyCppClass gMyClass;

//JNI
extern "C" 
{
    //Your JNI functions can use gMyClass
    void
    Java_package_name_initPath(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring jPath) 
    {
        const char* pPath = env->GetStringUTFChars(jPath, JNI_FALSE);
        gMyClass.mPath = pPath; //Of course you can use setters/getters if you want
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jPath, pPath);
    }
}

//MyCppClass implementation
MyCppClass::MyCppClass()
{
    //...
}
```

Now your gMyClass object contains the path as member, you don't have to pass it back and forth between native and Java.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. Yeah I ended up with something similar.
I have a permanent class that holds all classes and strings and permanent members.
I also found out that you actually don't need to send the class back to Java to keep it alive but you can just use static.
`static PermanentClass* perm_class = nullptr;`