# How can I keep a native object in state?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm currently using the JNI to interface with a library I built, but the library depends on the state of an object and is intended to invoke methods on the object to do work. How can I keep this object in memory without making it be global in the `.cpp` file interfacing the JNI?

What I would like it to look like is something like this:

```
public class Consumer {
    public NativeType workerObject;

    public native void methodOneToCallOnWorker();
    public native void methodTwoToCallOnWorker();
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to keep `workerObject` in state without making it global?

Comment: Probably see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397426/keep-some-sort-of-c-object-alive-over-multiple-jni-calls, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337268/what-is-the-correct-way-to-store-a-native-pointer-inside-a-java-object and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632367/passing-pointers-between-c-and-java-through-jni (possible duplicate?).

Comment: These definitely solve the problem. Thank you.